# Opentok what are the events to mute/unmute and on/off subscriber video in video conferencing

Tags: opentok, tokbox, subscriber, video-conferencing

Opentok what are the events to mute/unmute and on/off subscriber video in video conferencing
Everywhere I can only found -

```html
publisher.publishAudio(false);
publisher.publishAudio(true);
```

And for Video

```html
publisher.publishVideo(false);
publisher.publishVideo(true);
```

Nothing how to on/off particular subscriber video or Audio

Comment: Hi, how you added video icon on subscriber video?

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

On the subscriber object you have access to the `subscribeToAudio` and `subscribeToVideo` methods. These can be used to toggle subscription to audio/video for each subscription.  You can learn more about them at:

[subscribeToAudio](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#subscribeToAudio)

[subscribeToVideo](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#subscribeToVideo)

Comment: But how can I add video icon on subscriber video?